# Assigning icons system-wide based on filename without extension

Tags: finder, icon, file-extensions

I'd like Finder to display a particular icon for files based purely on its filename, not its extension. For instance, for a web project I have a Makefile sitting amidst PHP files, which all display the [Atom](https://atom.io/) logo:

[image]

The file already opens with Atom when double-clicked, even though TextEdit is technically my system's default text editor (which I never use, because Atom rules).

Is it possible to automatically assign an icon to makefiles system-wide, **without** manually copy+pasting an icon into it through the properties pane? Preferably without installing any third-party software, as this is really a cosmetic thing that's not worth having system bloat over.

I'm hoping there's some `defaults`-related thing I could tweak, or an entry in a `plist` file somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setting Atom icon via command line for Makefile

There is no direct way to set icons based on filename only, but one can set them via command line and then apply to all makefiles on the Mac.

Here are the steps to set `Atom's` icon to a specific `Makefile` via command line (assuming you Developer Tools are installed).

1. Get the Atom icon file from `/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/file.icns`
2. Convert the image to icon
   `sips -i file.icns`
3. Extract the icon to its own resource file 
   `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/DeRez -only icns file.icns > tmpicns.rsrc`
4. Append this resource to the file you want to icon-ize
   `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/Rez -append tmpicns.rsrc -o Makefile`
5. Use the resource to set the icon
   `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/SetFile -a C Makefile`
6. Restart your Mac

you can run `mdfind -name makefile` to get all the makefiles in your system and write a script to do the above on them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Although I'm guessing there's no way to apply the icon to all **future** Makefiles as well...? (I'm tipping the answer is "no", but that wouldn't surprise me).

Comment: Also, what does step #2 do? Isn't the `icns` format already an icon file?

Comment: in this case it is. But I have added that step so that you can convert other files to icons using this command, if required.